# C++ File Reading and storing in vector and finding string using vector on Linux environment

Tags: c++, linux, file, vector

I have been working on this for past 2 days and I not able to do anything on this.

**Scenario:** This is on Linux machine RHEL7 which has c++98
I am trying to read a text file and using vector I am storing all the contents in the text file line by line into the vector and find a string using vector. If the string matches, one block of codes executes, and if it doesn't the other block executes. The problem is I am not able to find if it read the file or not and if it reads the file then find login of vector doesn't work I guess. Every time I execute, it goes into to else block.

This is my piece of code-->It works fine in windows and doesn't work in Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string user;
    cout << "enter user" << endl;
    cin >> user;
    std::string userappend = "user,";
    userappend.append(user);
    userappend.append(",I");

    string myText;
    vector<string> v;

    ifstream MyReadFile("//etc//foldername//users.txt");

    while (getline(MyReadFile, myText))
        v.push_back(myText);

    if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), userappend) != v.end())
    {
        std::cout << "if block";
        std::cout << "Current User : " << userappend << endl
                  << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "nothing" << endl;
    }

    MyReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I am trying to create a dll file and .so file and dll works fine with this logic. After generating .so file, the string find logic or reading file logic is not working in linux. Please Help ME

Comment: try to check if the file was sucesfully opened

Comment: as you said I  tried and modified code to check while generated .so file whether it is able to read the file but it says unable to open file.  have give 777 permission to the file and when i write a standalone program in linux to read file and compile using g++ the stand program read the content but bow come the code for generating .so is not able to open file.

Comment: a common mistake is to assume the file is in a place where it is not. What is the working directory, where is the executable and where is `text.txt` ?

Comment: i have the file inside /etc/foldername/users..txt and inside the .so file I have given path as ifstream MyReadFile("//etc//foldername//users.txt");

Comment: thats not what you have written in your question

Comment: sorry about that just now i saw the path which I have mentioned wrongly in the question. I will correct it